# Mostrar modal al dar clic sobre boton creado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

Estoy tratando de mostrar un modal, al momento de dar clic sobre un botón creado dinamicamente.

Si lo tengo de esta manera se ejecuta pero inmediatamente se desaparece y no puedo hacer nada ya que la pagina se queda gris.

```
<script>
     function ModalGood() {
         $("#engModal").modal();
     };
</script>
```

pero si lo tengo de esta manera simplemente manda un error de JavaScript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("").click(function () {
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

y este es mi codigo de como creo el boton sobre como intent ejecutarlo al momento en que doy clic sobre el boton creado

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

            Button Btn_clic = (Button)sender;
            var name = Btn_clic.Text;

            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposFCHOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == name && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            List<Button> Botones = new List<Button>();

            var TeamFCH = ListOfEquiposFCHOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
            {
                Button newButton = new Button();
                newButton.ID = "Btn_" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.Text = team;
                newButton.Click += new EventHandler(Info_Click);
                newButton.OnClientClick = "ModalGood();";
                Botones.Add(newButton);

                GoodPanel.Controls.Add(newButton);

                newButton.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
            }

        }
```

En el Segundo ejemplo decidi dejarlo en blanco ya que no se como darle el id que se genera dinamicamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion era facil en realidad, solo me faltana un `return false` en el script

```
<script>
    function ModalGood() {
        $("#engModal").modal();
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Los eventos en elementos que se crean dinamicamente se manejan o capturan de manera distinta en java script con jquery

```
$("ul#pestanas_facturacion  ").on("click", "span",function (e) {});
```

En el ejemplo anterior estoy capturando el evento click al elemento span que fue agregado dinamicamente a la lista Ul
en el caso del botón seria

```
     $("div#contenedor  ").on("click", "button",function (e) {
 $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

MEJOR EXPLICADO 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>



</head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<body>



</body>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).on("ready", function(e){
    $("panel#GoodPanel").on("click", "button", function (e) { $("#engModal").modal(); }); 
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: nunca antes lo habia hecho de esta manera, podrias explicar major la parte de `ul#pestanas_facturacion `

Comment: Modifique la respuesta dime si entiendes... para ello yo uso jquery...

Comment: para mostrar los modales yo uso javascript

Comment: Es la misma cosa... jquery es una libreria de java script apenas veas  como es de simple el java sccript con jquery ya no usaras tanto el java script puro

Comment: `0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method ` me manda ese error, he puesto el script de la siguiente manera `<script>
        $("panel#GoodPanel").on("click", "button", function (e) {
            $("#engModal").modal();
        });
    </script>`

Comment: Primero agrega este escript al header <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> luego debes agregar este otro script al final del body por lo general lo hago yo  <script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).on("ready", function(e){
$("panel#GoodPanel").on("click", "button", function (e) { $("#engModal").modal(); }); 
});
</script>

Comment: Volvi a editar la respuesta

Comment: `Unhandled exception at line 2, column 31689 in https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js` y tambien me aparece este `0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'popover'`

Comment: si quieres envíame por correo  mi correo es valcarcel-01@hotmail.com

Comment: Listo, ya lo solucione, fue taaaaan tonta la solucion, solo me faltaba un `return false;` en el script

Comment: jajaj bueno me alegra mucho yo me acababa de dar por vencido.....

Answer (score 0):

Si este es el nombre de tu botón `Unnamed1`, para llamarlo desde jQuery:

```
$("#<%= Unnamed1.ClientID %>").click(function () {
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

Comment: el nombre no recibe ningun tipo de nombre, solo texto y un id

Comment: cuál es el id de tu control?

Comment: se genera igual en automatic, al momento en que se crea en el foreach, se le asigna un id, un ejemplo es que ahi dice que se llamara Btn_ y el texto que llevara el boton el ejemplo Btn_512